# XML file doesn't work in Android application when the XML has children/layers?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, inputstream

While experimenting with parsing XML files in Android applciation(s) I came across an issue/bug. Whenever I have an xml files with only 1 "layer" of children it parses just fine but when I have an XML with more than one layer (children of children) it suddenly doesn't parse it.

Now, I know it has nothing to do with my parsing code itself because it works 100% of the time in a normal Java application but when I want to incorporate it in an Android application you have to create the InputStream etc. Maybe it has something to do with that?

Here is my code for initiating the parsing. It never goes passed the dom = builder.parse(input_src) :

```
dickbutt = true;

    categories_list = new ArrayList<Category>();
    XML = xml_file;


    //instantiate String object sto be used throughout class
    object_name = object;
    class_type = xml_class;
    value_pointer = pointer;


    //create an input source for the bytestream
    InputStream input_src = activity.getAssets().open(XML);

    //get factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();


    //get instance of document builder to build document from xml file
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();


    dom = builder.parse(input_src);  //NEVER COMPLETES THIS

    dickbutt = false;


    parseDocument();
```

I can't seem to add my logcat as the emulator doesn't work and can't install the Google USB driver.

Comment: Restart adb. You don`t need Google USB Driver.

Comment: Whenever I start ADB my command line just goes through a bunch of commands and then proceeds to close

Comment: The solution I found is open the DDMS perspective and select the device and the running process on the Device window. With that done, the LogCat returns to life.

Comment: Any logcat error? if don't can you try placing some log lines to find where does it stop parsing ?

Comment: @iFrey it stops at     dom = builder.parse(input_src); and dickbutt never becomes false

Comment: @TeRRo my device doesn't even show on the DDMS

Comment: @user3774329 Are you sure that clicked USB Debug in your device?

Comment: Restart Eclipse or Android Studio.

Comment: Still nothing. Any guesses as to what might cause the problem? The parsing seems to work when I use an XML file  with only 1 layer of children but whenever I add another one it just doesn't go passed the dom = builder..... line

Comment: @TeRRo Think i  figured it out. The XML file is about 50,000 lines which might be too much for an Android phone to handle. Could that be a possibility?

Comment: try to set android:largeHeap="true" in the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The XML file was too big for an Android device. The file was about 60k liens and once I trimmed it down it worked perfectly